# GET Request working in browser but giving error SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in curl

Tags: ssl, curl

When I send the request to https://DOMAIN:443/path it works correctly in every web browser I've tried. But when it comes to curl (and wget) I get an error. I already recompiled openssl and curl (latest versions) with not changes.

> curl -vv https://DOMAIN:443/path

**Output**
​* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to DOMAIN (IPADDRESS) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to DOMAIN:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to​ DOMAIN:443

**Curl version**

```
curl 7.61.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.61.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.32.1 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-07-11
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm also having this kind of error

*Trying 58.71.19.141...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to so.ngcp.ph (58.71.19.141) port 8081 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* ignoring certificate verify locations due to disabled peer verification
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to so.ngcp.ph:8081
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error I was referring to might happen when the firewall is blocking Curl and wget connections. This theory is supported by these facts:

- I received the same error using different operative systems, configurations, IP addresses and the result was the same.
- Browser based request were successful.
- Using alternatives to curl and wget worked perfectly (I used [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) and [kurly](https://gitlab.com/davidjpeacock/kurly))

So, problem solved for me. I hope this answer can help anyone facing the same problem.